# How do I make solid headers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, memoir

I am trying to replicate the formatting of a certain standardized test. It looks a little bit like this:

[image: This is the form.]

I'm going to try `memoir` and `tikz` a little bit today, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: The easiest way is to scan it and use \includepicture and fancyhdr.  If you still unsatisfied you can use everypage and \raisebox.

Comment: What does the 2 represent? The chapter number?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes.

Comment: @SimonKuang I updated my answer with the settings using `memoir`. I initially overlooked this from your question and my first answer was for the standard `book`; now I've provided the settings for `memoir`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option using TikZ and the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package (adjust the settings according to your needs). According to comments, the first page of each chapter should also have the new page style, so

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{solid}
```

was used:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows}

\newlength\GrayBarHt
\newlength\BlackBarWd
\setlength\GrayBarHt{1.5cm}
\setlength\BlackBarWd{10pt}
\newcommand\ChapterNumberFont{\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily}

\newcommand\SolidHeader{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \path
    node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=0pt,text width=\textwidth,anchor=south west,minimum height=\GrayBarHt]
    at (current page header area.west)
    (box)
    {}
    node[fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=\GrayBarHt,text width=\BlackBarWd,anchor=west]
    at (box.west)
    (bboxl)
    {}
    node[fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=\GrayBarHt,text width=\BlackBarWd,anchor=east]
    at (box.east)
    (bboxr)
    {}
    node[font=\ChapterNumberFont,anchor=west]
    at (bboxl.east)
    {\thechapter}
    node[font=\ChapterNumberFont,anchor=east]
    at (bboxr.west)
    {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand\SolidFooter{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \path
  node[anchor=north west,align=left,font=\sffamily\bfseries]
    at (current page footer area.west)
    {Unathorized copying or reuse of any part of this page is illegal\\[5ex]\thepage}
  node[fill=black,single arrow,text=white,anchor=north west]
    at (current page footer area.east)
    {\enspace CONTINUE\enspace};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\makepagestyle{solid}
\makeevenhead{solid}{\SolidHeader}{}{}
\makeoddhead{solid}{\SolidHeader}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{solid}{\SolidFooter}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{solid}{\SolidFooter}{}{}

% First page of chapters will also have the style
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{solid}

\pagestyle{solid}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Since no information was provided in the question for fotters on odd-numbered pages, I used the same as for even-numbered pages, but you can easily change this.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's not quite correct. Can you make the light gray bar stretch only across the text block, with black rectangles and numbers on  both sides? Also, what do `\x1` and `\x2` refer to?

Comment: @SimonKuang I see. I misinterpreted your image. I'll correct the code. `\x1` and `\x2` are part of the `let` syntax for calculations. They are the x-coordinates of `\p1` and `\p2`, respectively, defined before.

Comment: @SimonKuang Unswer updated. Since this design is simpler, now there's no need for the calculations using `\x2` and `\x1`.

Comment: This is lovely. One thing though: can you make it work for all pages? It looks like it only works for the pages after the first.

Comment: @SimonKuang. Sure. As soon as I arrive home I'll produce the code.

Comment: Nevermind. The solution is to use `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{solid}`.

Comment: @SimonKuang Indeed. Glad to hear you found it. I updated the answer introducing this and also a simplification to the code.